# Ror4 Ajax executing javascript on page load

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having a problem with the unobtrusive javascript in my application.  I put an alert into the js.erb file to help me debug, but it runs whenever I load my page, and does nothing when I click the button.  I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def new
    @user = User.new
end

def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
        if @user.save
            format.html { redirect_to :root, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
            format.js   { render :text => "FINISHED THE AJAX REQUEST" }
        else
            format.html { render action: "new" }
            format.js   {}
        end
    end
end

def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def index
    @user  = User.find(params[:id])
end

private

    def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email)
end

end
```

create.js.erb

```
alert("BUTTON CLICKED");
$('.button').text("Thank You!");
$('.button').animate({"background-color":"#088A08"},300);
$('#e_submit').css("box-shadow","0 0 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
$('#e_submit').val("");
```

welcome.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(User.new, remote: true) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :email, class: "e_submit", placeholder:"Enter your email" %>               
<%= f.submit "Subscribe", class: "button" %>
<% end %>
```

I can't figure out why @user instead of User.new doesn't work, but that's a question for a different day.

Comment: Wrap your JQuery-Code inside the ready function -> ```$( document ).ready( function(){ YOUR CODE } )```. If you want to load your JS-files only for a specific page/controller have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990885/how-to-load-page-specific-rails-4-js-files) thread.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out.  This all stemmed from my misunderstanding of javascript and where it goes in a rails 4 application.  I put it in app/assets/javascripts/ when I should have put it in app/views/users along with the view HTML files.

When I put it in that directory, it no longer needed any of the ready function stuff.  Also, I had to remove format.js   {} with just format.js.  This is now working. Thanks!