# The right way to include page-specific JavaScript in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to include this, for example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#my-modal').modal(options)
});
```

In one specific place in a rails app. In my case the file is called views/modals/mymodal.html.erb. There and only there.

I can't figure out how to do that without getting it on all pages as would happen if I put it in assets.

Answer (score 7):

These are some useful tricks

## #1 with file js

- Create file `your.js` for your javascript
- call file `your.js` on specific your layout
- remove `//= require_tree .` on `application.js`
- add `your.js` to asset percompile `on config/application.rb` : `config.assets.precompile += %w( your.js )`

---

## #2 put into specific file non layout (not recommended)

put your js script with javascript tag on `mymodal.html.erb`

---

## #3 use if..else..

put your js script into `layout/yourlayout.html.erb` and use `if.. else..` logic.

example :

> ```
>  <% if current_page?(yourspecific_path) %>
>   <script language="text/javascript">
>    your javascript here ..
>   </script>
>  <% end %>
> ```

Read more [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/current_page%3F) about `current_page?`

Or use `request.fullpath` to get current full path

example :

> ```
>  <% if request.fullpath == yourspecific_path %>
>   <script language="text/javascript">
>    your javascript here ..
>   </script>
>  <% end %>
> ```

Read more [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-fullpath) about `request.fullpath`

**Also you can combine #1 and #3 if you want script put into file `.js`**

cheers

Answer (score 3):

Given the JS file you want to include is named `my_modal.js`:

1. Place your `JS` files placed in `assets/javascripts` in some directory inside of
   `assets/javascripts`, for example `application`.
2. Change line `//= require_tree .` to `//= require_tree application` in your `application.js` (it prevents loading `my_modal.js` on every page).
3. Place your `my_modal.js` in `assets/javasctripts`
4. Add `my_modal.js` to `config.assets.precompile` array (`config assets.precompile += ['my_modal.js']`) in your `application.rb`.
5. Put `javascript_include_tag 'my_modal'` in the view you want this file included

You can go to [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#controller-specific-assets) for reference.

Answer (score 2):

One of the solution is to insert our javascript in to its own file: [Reference Link](http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/page-specific-javascript-in-rails/)

For example :

// app/assets/javascripts/alert.js

```
alert("My example alert box.");
```

And including this file only in the view we want it to execute:

```
<%# app/views/page/contact.html.erb %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "alert" %>
<h1>Contact</h1>
<p>This is the contact page</p>
```

And don’t forget to include your new file in the list of files to be compiled:

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.assets.precompile += %w( alert.js )
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but for anyone viewing this today I think I've come up with something better.

[Punchbox Gem for Rails](https://github.com/kieraneglin/punchbox)

With this, you can write code like:

```
class Post {
  controller() {
    // Runs on every action
  }
  index() {
    // Runs on just the index action
  }
}

Punchbox.on('Posts', Post);
```

(You can also create an object instead of a class.  See the docs)

I've written about this much more in depth here: https://kierancodes.com/blog/page-specific-javascript-in-rails-4

Answer (score 0):

[jquery-readyselector](https://github.com/Verba/jquery-readyselector) is a plugin that "Extends `$().ready()` to provide a convenient syntax for page-specific script"

1. Install [jquery-readyselector](https://github.com/Verba/jquery-readyselector)
2. Create some CSS classes

   ```
   <body class="<%= controller_name %> <%= action_name %>">
   ```
3. Scope your javascript to your page

   ```
   $("#my-modal").ready(function() {
     $('#my-modal').modal(options)
   });
   ```

More info in this answer [How to load page specific rails 4 js files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990885/how-to-load-page-specific-rails-4-js-files#answer-29314895)